# Div position not working with any value settings

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a gmap on a main div set in the body as below. Then in the javascript we have add a new div as below. The problem is that the div with table keep appearing on the top left of the page and never goes to any other location even how I try to change values of `document.getElementById("auto").style.top="35px";` and             `document.getElementById("auto").style.left="35px";`

```
var contents = document.createElement("div");
contents.style.width="300px";
contents.style.height="100px";

var htmlString = '<table style="background-color: #ffffff;">\r\n';
htmlString += '<tr><td>Name</td><td valign="top"><input id="nm" type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td></tr>\r\n';
htmlString += '<tr><td>Description</td><td valign="top"><input id="desc" type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td></tr>\r\n';
htmlString += '<tr><td>Client</td><td valign="top">'+clientList+'</td></tr>\r\n';                          
htmlString += '<tr>\r\n';
htmlString += '<td>&#160;</td><td><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="editFeature(\'Point\')"> <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="saveFeatureCancel()"></td>\r\n';
htmlString += '</tr>\r\n';
htmlString += '</table>\r\n';               

contents.innerHTML="<form name='form2' id='form2' onsubmit='javascript:codeAddress();return false;'><div id='auto' style='z-index:5; position:relative'>"+htmlString+"</div></form>";
document.getElementById('map').appendChild(contents);
document.getElementById("contents").style.position="relative";
document.getElementById("auto").style.top="35px";
document.getElementById("auto").style.left="35px";
```

Main codes for the body

```
<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There are so many problems with this code. Why are you adding it all dynamically to begin with? Either way, here is a jsFiddle that works: jsfiddle.net/7hzct/1/

Comment: @Neil what are the major problem that I should resolve then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are never setting the id of the "contents" DOM element to "contents".**  Simple fix to just add this (last) line.

```
var contents = document.createElement("div");
contents.style.width="300px";
contents.style.height="100px";
contents.id = 'contents';
```

[Here's my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrY4g/).

Comment: ok I will add that id but how to put the it at the bottom right?

Comment: Check out the jsFiddle for my exact positioning of it, but you just need to assign it at some point before you use document.getElementById('contents').

Comment: I have checked the jsFiddle what point you want me to assign? I have now tried document.getElementById("contents").style.position="absolute";      document.getElementById("contents").style.top="35px";          document.getElementById("contents").style.left="35px"; but what should I do the bring it to bottom?

Comment: @biz14 if you want to position it at the bottom and not the top, use the `bottom` CSS attribute instead of `top`.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard I have tried this document.getElementById("contents").style.position="absolute";    document.getElementById("contents").style.bottom="100px";      document.getElementById("contents").style.right="-55px"; this works now but why must I put negative for right else it stop does not really goes to full right.

Comment: You need to assign contents.id = 'contents' e.g. the (last) line. You don't have it in your example.

Comment: I have done at the very top after this line contents.style.height="100px"; contents.id = 'contents'; is that fine ?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `top` and the `left` for the element with id, 'auto' not 'map'

So you may have to use,

`document.getElementById("map").style.position="absolute";` or `document.getElementById("map").style.position="fixed";`

and

```
document.getElementById("map").style.top="35px";
document.getElementById("map").style.left="35px";
```

Comment: not the map will remain I just want to change is the content div not the map.

Comment: the map div is the div holding the map. The content div will be on top of that map. So I want the content div to be at the bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here. See working jsFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/7hzct/1/

First off, you should (as it seems from your comments that you have noticed) set the position to `absolute`, not `relative`.

Next up, you are adding `div#contents` to `div#map`. It seems from your comments you want to add it to the body (next to the `#map`):

```
document.body.appendChild(contents);
```

Furthermore, you are setting the `top` and `left` coordinates for `#auto`, you want to use `bottom` and `right` and set them for `#contents`:

```
document.getElementById("contents").style.position="absolute";
document.getElementById("contents").style.bottom="35px";
document.getElementById("contents").style.right="35px";
```

I haven't touched your html string, but it is quite horrendous to read - **don't use inline CSS so much!**. Also, `valign` has been deprecated since HTML 4.01.

Comment: @Neils yes I have set it as absolute not relative. No I dont want to add next to the #map but on on its top. I have this and working now do see any problem? document.getElementById('map').appendChild(contents);    document.getElementById("contents").style.position="absolute";    document.getElementById("contents").style.bottom="100px";      document.getElementById("contents").style.right="-55px";

Comment: @biz14 I'm sorry, this makes no sense to me. What are you saying?